# How would I change the action bar's color?

Tags: android

How would I change the action bar's color?

Comment: Your layout `xml` file you are using with your current activity has most of the design attributes like color.

Comment: You reaaaaaally searched hard? [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589943/android-3-0-actionbar-changing-colors) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color) [4](https://www.google.ca/search?q=android+change+action+bar+color)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

Fetch the id from the Android resource (just like we fetch id from R.java)

```
int titleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
```

Now you use `TextView` with the id we fetch.

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(titleId);
textView.setTextColor(colorId);
```

Have a look at to [Advance Styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#AdvancedStyles) in Android.